# Is there a way to exhaust a reified generic using when statement in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to perform different actions based on the type of generic the function is running with. It feels to me like the compiler has all the information to not use `else` but the code will not compile without it. Am I missing something or is there another more obvious way to do that in Kotlin?
Example:

```
sealed class A {
    data class A1(val a: String): A()
    data class A2(val a: String): A()
}

inline fun <reified T: A> function() {
    return when (T::class) {
        A.A1::class -> {  }
        A.A2::class -> {  }
        else -> {  } // Problem: Does not compile without the else branch.
    }
}
```